# Setting Function Boolean var to False or True

Tags: vb.net

I have the Function below that is suppose to set the property for the items below to True or False. I am able to do it on all properties except for this one:

```
.Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", False)")
```

When I try to replace False with my parameter boolStatus, and I run the function, it will not change. So I gave up and just left it as False, but I really needed to change from False to True and vice versa otherwise my function is only half working. As it stands right now, I would have to create a second function where I would set the line to True, I am pretty certain that is double work.

```
Module sheetView

    Public xlWB As Excel.Workbook = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
    Public xlWS As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

        Function ViewSheets(boolStatus As Boolean) As String

        'This function selects a dashboard and hides
        'the gridlines, headings, tabs and toolbar.

        '@parameter sheetName, calls the sheet to be selected
        '@parameter status, sets the objects to view or hide


        With xlWS

            .Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            'Disable the following controls
            .Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = boolStatus
            .Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = boolStatus
            .Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = boolStatus
            .Application.DisplayFormulaBar = boolStatus
            .Application.DisplayStatusBar = boolStatus
            .Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", False)")


            .Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End With


        Return ""

    End Function

End Module
```

What am I doing wrong with that line?

Comment: Perhaps something like `.Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", " + boolStatus + ")")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
.Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", " + boolStatus.ToString() +")")
```

Or something similar

> Please check this code for exact VB.Net syntax

Comment: Same thing I was thinking.  Syntax looks correct - though `&` might work (or could even be needed  - VB.NET gets confusing to me on that sometimes).

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you're passing in a string to the macro function, so you need to concatenate the boolStatus with the string, like this:

```
.Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", " + boolStatus.ToString() + ")")
```

Your previous code was probably adding the variable name into the string, hence the issue. For example, if your previous code was:

```
.Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", boolStatus)")
```

The argument passed to `ExecuteExcel4Macro` would look like Show.ToolBar("Ribbon", boolStatus).

Using first code snippet above, it would look like:

```
Show.ToolBar("Ribbon", False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I could not figure out the issue. I tried your solution and it worked perfect.